# how to change html input type date placeholder value as a curruent Date i m using angular

Tags: html, angular, date

```html
<input type="date" name ="Date"
   class="form-control" [formControl]="dateCtrl">
```

```js
getDateCtr() {

    var today = new Date(this.dateCtrl.value);
    var dd = String(today.getDate() ).padStart(2, '0');
    var mm = String(today.getMonth()+1).padStart(2, '0');
    var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
    this.date = dd + '-' + mm + '-' + yyyy;
    this.loadAll();

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I used the information from Mozilla regarding [date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date), and all that you are missing in your HTML is the **value** option:

```html
<input type="date" name ="Date" class="form-control" value="{{getDateCtr()}} [formControl]="dateCtrl">
```

I do not know what the `this.loadAll()` is meant to accomplish. But the JS I worked with looked like this:

```js
getDateCtr() :string {
    var today = new Date();
    var d = today.getDate().toFixed().padStart(2, '0');
    var m = (today.getMonth() + 1).toFixed().padStart(2, '0');
    var y = today.getFullYear().toFixed();
    var sday = y + "-" + m + "-" + d
    return sday;
    }
```

Note that the return type is `:string` for the function.